# New Job and a big Mistake with Company Culture

Tags: careers, leadership

I've started a new job at a large (~ 500 person) company after a career in startups.  I joined the team based on the cutting edge technology stack, small size, and great people.  I had heard bad things about the culture of the company at large, but weighed the quality of my small team vs. the general average of the larger company.

I am now 4 months in and the leadership of my small team has just quit.  The team has been annexed by other leaders in the company.  The overall company culture is bureaucratic and difficult to work with.  Having lost our group champions we're being pushed around and forced to make decisions that don't make sense for our product.

I am in a situation I do not like and I did not sign up for.  How do I make the best of this?

Is it best to leave ASAP?  Is it wiser to try and make something good of the situation?

Comment: Only _you_ can answer this. All I can say is that you, alone, will not change the company culture (not with that size).

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with internal company politics than any specific aspect of the company's culture.  Management is trying to dictate product direction.  That's a common situation in all sorts of companies, large and small.

Comment: Maybe the question should be about getting a new supervisor to understand the things that made your group successful?

Comment: I would suggest editing this into a question about how leaving in response to the depature of a supervisor/co-worker would be perceived by a potential new employer.  How is it likely to impact your career.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should leave.  It's no good working somewhere you're not happy and there's no reason why you can't enjoy your job.

However, assuming this is a permanent position (as opposed to a short-term contract/consultancy role) then 4 months seems like a short time to be in a role before moving on and it may raise awkward questions with potential future employers.  Basically, you don't want to be negative in anyway at an interview if you can help it.

My advice would be to tough it for at least another month, then start applying for new roles.  Hopefully by the time you get something lined up it'll have been about 6 months and that doesn't look too bad.

However, if you can, try and do a full year before moving on.  Remember, all experience is good experience and you can still learn a lot of things even in an organisation with a poor culture.

Good luck!